# Interactions not saving to xdb when processing custom events?

Tags: xdb, xconnect

In my SC 9.3 solution I have a custom page event that I am firing, converting, and wanting to store in xdb. When I debug the code:

- I can see the events getting registered as expected
- I can inspect the current interaction (via `Tracker.Current.Interaction.ToVisitData()`) and all information pertaining to my custom event appears as expected
- I can see my custom converter running as expected and creating the custom event when I end the session (via `Session.Abandon()`)

However, when I run this database query, I am not seeing **any** new interactions getting added whatsoever; not even the default ones such as `PageViewEvent`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Project_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM [Project_Xdb.Collection.Shard1].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]
ORDER BY Created DESC
```

I also don't see any data in my `Interactions_Staging` databases.

When I remove my custom processor from the patch config, everything begins working as normal again, and interactions are saved in xdb once the session is abandoned (except for my custom event, of course).

Here is how I registered the custom converter:

```
<convertToXConnectEvent>
    <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToGoal, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect']" type="Client.Project.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToMyCustomEvent, Client.Project"/>
</convertToXConnectEvent>
```

The showconfig.aspx appears as follows:

```
<convertToXConnectEvent patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config">
    <processor type="Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEvent.ConvertPageEventDataToEmailEvent, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentDelivery.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageDataToPageViewEvent, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertOutcomeDataToOutcome, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToCampaignEvent, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToDownloadEvent, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToSearchEvent, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToGoal, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect"/>

    <!-- My custom converter --> 
    <processor type="Client.Project.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToMyCustomEvent, Client.Project, Client.Project" patch:source="Client.Project.config"/>
    
    <!-- Ensure this processor is the last in the pipeline, because this processor converts page event data to default XConnect Event object. -->
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToEvent, Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.Tracking.ConvertToXConnectEvent.CopyFxmOutcomeData, Sitecore.FXM" runIfAborted="true" patch:source="Sitecore.FXM.config"/>
</convertToXConnectEvent>
```

I am working off of the following Sitecore guides:

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/events.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/convert-a-page-event.html

Why might this be happening? What can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Are there any exceptions showing in sitecore logs relating xconnect model? Or in the xconnect collection instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't recall what the exact solution was (though I don't believe it was due to config settings), I did post a working solution in this [blog post](https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/storing-full-urls-in-page-view-events). There is quite a bit of code involved, so I won't include it.

The key was this:

> When I remove my custom processor from the patch config, everything begins working as normal again

Therefore, there was likely a defect in the code that was somehow preventing any interactions from being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your resulting showconfig.aspx it looks like you have specified the assembly two times?

Should it not be this:

```
type="Client.Project.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToMyCustomEvent, Client.Project"
```

Rather than

```
type="Client.Project.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToMyCustomEvent, Client.Project, client.project"
```

If that was just a typo, then are there any error messages in either sitecore instance or xconnext collection, relating to defining your custom event? Did you deploy your custom model to all the necessary places?

Comment: It has been a while, but I recall that this was not the issue.

Comment: Looking at it a bit more, I can confirm that it was in fact a typo while writing the question and not material to the problem.